# Почему бот зависает при переходе на стейт?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Бот зависает при переходе на стейт до любого следующего действия, не могу понять в чём причина. Весь код большой, поэтому приведу, как мне кажется, проблемные участки.

На первом участке кода при нажатии кнопки `начать поиск` пользователя просят ввести город, если его нет в бд, то его перекидывает на стейт ввода города. Если пользователь ввел город ранее, то его перекидывает на следующий этап.

На втором участке хендлер получения города и записи его в бд и переход на следующий этап, что и в первом хендлере.

На третьем участке обозначен следующий этап куда пользователь в любом случае должен попасть, при переходе на этот этап бот залагивает, пока не нажать любую кнопку либо ввести любой текст. Как это можно исправить?

№1

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def start_2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == 'Начать поиск':
        con = sqlite3.connect('bot_users.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT city FROM bot_users WHERE chat_id=%d" % message.from_user.id)
        city = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
        cur.close()
        con.close()
        if not city:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите ваш город")
            await bs.waiting_for_city.set()
        else:
            await bs.waiting_for_search.set()
```

№2

```py
@dp.message_handler(state=bs.waiting_for_city, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def get_city(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.lower() not in cities:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вашего города нет в списке')
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Нажмите кнопку "Начать поиск ещё раз"')
        await state.finish()
    else:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['user_city'] = message.text.title()
        city = data['user_city']
        con = sqlite3.connect('bot_users.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("update bot_users set city = '%s' where chat_id=%d" % (city, message.from_user.id))
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
        await state.finish()
        await bs.waiting_for_search.set()
```

№3

```py
@dp.message_handler(state=bs.waiting_for_search, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def search(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вам будут показаны машины')
    con = sqlite3.connect('bot_users.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT city FROM bot_users WHERE chat_id=%d' % message.from_user.id)
    city = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
    print(city)
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cars where city='%s'" % city)
    all_cars = cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute("SELECT balance from bot_users where chat_id=%d" % message.from_user.id)
    user_bal = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
    if not all_cars:
        await message.reply('В данный момент нет доступных машин')
    else:
        for x in cars:
            body = x[1] + ', ' + x[2] + ', ' + x[3] + '\n\n' + x[4] + '\n\n' + 'Цена: ' + str(x[6]) + 'рублей.'
            await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo=x[5], caption=body)
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

Comment: Добавьте кучу принтов в ваш код, а-ля `print("Метка N1")`, чтобы найти строчку на котором он зависает. А вообще подозреваю, что БД не справляется

Comment: @Inventor зависает на третьем участке, сразу же, пока не нажмешь еще одну кнопку, до бд даже не доходит

Comment: Строчка кода какая?

Comment: @Inventor во 2ом участке последняя(она отрабатывает), которая перебрасывает на третий и тут зависание

Comment: `await bs.waiting_for_search.set()` на этой функции зависает?

Comment: @Inventor да, до следующего действия любого

Comment: А что эта функция делает?

Comment: @Inventor `bs` это класс, `waiting_for_search` это стейт, функция `set` приводит ее в ожидание и перекидывает на 3ый участок кода

Comment: Первое - спешу расстроить, но ваше форматирование sql-запросов никак не спасет от sql-инъекций (это как замечание к коду) - используйте для `sqlite` вместо `%s` - `?`. Теперь о вашей проблеме - я, к сожалению, опыта с `aiogram` не имею, только с десяток ботов на `telebot`, но предполагаю, что `bs.waiting_for_search.set()` это улучшенный аналог `register_next_step_handler` в том же самом `telebot`-е. Мне не совсем понятна логика работы кода с точки зрения проектирования, но  зачем создавать стейт во втором участке в блоке `else`, если можно просто вызывать там функцию `search` на отработку?

Comment: А если так подумать - по идее после заполнения уже в базу пользователем города - `if message.text == 'Начать поиск':` вернет просто хендлер 3 стейта, но раз у вас берется значение города из базы - зачем тогда его там вызывать?

Comment: @DeNRuDi спасибо, помогло, можете оформить как ответ!